# No me corre función del método AJAX

Tags: php, html, jquery, ajax, phpmyadmin

tengo un problema con un button. Verán, lo que necesito es al clickar el boton, que me retorne todos los valores de una tabla de una base de datos que fue creada anteriormente en phpMyAdmin. Adjuntaré el codigo.

Este es parte del codigo del index donde está el button y un onclick que esta enlazado a un main ajax

```
<div class="ord1">
              <div class="col-md-5 mt-4">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary btn-block ord1" onclick="enviarDatos()">Enviar</button>
              </div>
</div>
```

Acá está la función desde el main ajax

```
function enviarDatos(){

$.ajax({
    'url':'http://localhost:8080/dashboard/light-bootstrap-dashboard-master/examples/backend.php',
    'type':'GET',
    'dataType':'Json',
    success:function(objSend){
        console.log(objSend)

    }

})
```

}

Y finalmente adjunto el backend, que algo me dice que algo por aqui esta el error

```
<?php

header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');


$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "evaluacion3";

    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
     
}

//  $Nombre="Juan gonzalez";
//  $Correo="diego@gmail.cl";
//  $Contacto="Siuuuuuuu";

//  $sql = "insert into usuarios (Correo, Nombre, Contacto) values ('".$Correo."','".$Nombre."','".$Contacto."')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Se ingresó correctamente";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();
echo json_encode(
    array(
        'resp'=>true,

    )

 );
```

?>

Comment: Cualquier información extra que sea necesaria haganmelo saber, de ante mano, graciass

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema? ¿El `console.log` que tienes en el `success` muestra algo? Por otra parte, si pusiste esto en la petición: `'dataType':'Json'` luego **no puedes** emitir cadenas simples en el servidor, debes meter todo en un array (también los errores) y emitirlos con `json_encode`, poque la petición espera en todo momento un json.

Comment: Dices pretender la devolución de todos los valores de una tabla, pero no veo por ninguna parte la consulta SQL que lo haga. Es más, veo esto: `$conn->query($sql)` pero no veo que es $sql, no está definido, y para terminar, no veo despues que vayas a devolver sus valores, sino `true` (me imagino que has hecho un copia/pega de otra cosa -un insert- y te falta adaptarlo bien, pues inténtalo!)

Comment: Perdón, me falto aclarar que necesito un respuesta del console.log y al clickear el botón no me devuelve nada. Me extraña, ya que estoy reutilizando el codigo y en otra página si me retornaba los valores.

Comment: ¿Como te va a devolver nada si no realiza ninguna consulta y seguramente se para en $conn->query($sql) con algun error?   Busca $sql en tu backend.php y date cuenta que no hace nada, lo tienes comentado.

Comment: ¿Estás revisando la consola? ¿Ves algún error allí? Pon un alert en tu función y veirifica si está entrando en ese bloque de código? Verifica también si tu URL funciona, y si muestra algo, copiando y pegando en el navegador: `http://localhost:8080/dashboard/light-bootstrap-dashboard-master/examples/backend.php`  Son pasos básicos de depuración que deberías aplicar cuando un código no funcione. Haz esas depuraciones y dinos cuál es el resultado.

Comment: sii, la consola no me arrojaba nada pero ya pude. Gracias a todos.

Comment: Si ya pudiste me alegro... pero seria de agradecer que compartieras con todos tu solución, creando una respuesta contestandote a ti mismo, para que los demás tambien sepamos que has hecho. No se trata solo de solucionar tus problemas, sino de ayudarnos y aprender los unos de los otros,